# Which regression model we use if we have each independent variables are in level?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

I want to predict the y variable, my Y variable is in numeric, I have more than 15 independents variables , all are in ordinal levels  like (good , better, best) , ( Acidic, not acidic) so on.. So each independent variables in levels .

I have data for year 2010 to 2016 , and I want to predict for year 2017.

Any one guide me which regression model I have to use in this case ?
I am thinking multiple regression analysis , is it correct way if I have independents variables in levels?

I have 2000 data observations , and response variables are 18 all are in levels.

I am using sci kit-learn , python library.

Comment: Nothing prohibits you from using classical regression model. Just decide which of your variables is better to split into dummy and which remain ordinal.

Comment: @StudentT ,using ANOVA , can I predict my dependent variable?  So I am confuse in Regression analysis

Comment: @Bogdan, oh i see, how can I do that ? to split into dummy variables and remain ordinal? any algorithm need to use?

Comment: @StudentT, Oh i see, there is any algorithm in machine learning if they gives which model is use in this data?

Comment: As you have many observation it is possible to split into dummy every variable (without risk of overfitting). Suppose you have some variables with levels (good normal bad). If coefficients something like 5 (normal) 10 (good) then you may use ordinal variable as its coefficient will be 5. But if you have something like 1 and 50 then it is no clear step so better to use dummy. You may also formalize procedure using coefficients test but according to my experience just looking at coefficients will be enough.

Comment: @Bogdan , do you mean I have to convert all x1....xn independent variables in single dummy variable? And how to convert my coefficients values (b1,b2...bn) in dummy coefficients?:(

Comment: @Kiran Prajapati what are your variables and how did you score the responses indicated as levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your independent variables are clearly ordinal.  Those are tricky to deal with, but one approach that I have recently been using is optimal scaling.  In SAS you can do this with PROC TRANSREG; in R with the opscale package. I don't use Python, but Googling found [this](https://github.com/alubbock/pyopscale/tree/master/pyopscale)

Comment: Thanks for guide, it's okay I will do in R,   So basically using Opscale  we get single value for our independents variables ? And next I have to use simple regression ,right?

Comment: I have only done this in SAS, I don't know exactly how R's function behaves.

Comment: .I have SAS too. Can you please help me, hows working PROC TRANSREG in SAS? I search in googlinh found this                https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_transreg_sect006.htm  , Can I use logistic regression in this case ?

Comment: I wrote a [presentation/paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279188432_Alternative_methods_of_regression_when_OLS_is_not_right) on using it.   If that site doesn't work for you, you can look for "Alternative methods of regression when OLS is not right".

Comment: thank you so much sir, I have single doubt is  1) If our independent variables are in ordinal then we use PROC TRANSRED in SAS  this is only one solution to do this or we can use multiple logistic regression also? it's not possible logistic regression in this case ?  if not possible then I have only concentrate in your research paper . thanks

Comment: You can transform both the dependent and independent variables with TRANSREG, including the LOGIT transform

Comment: PROC TRASREG  is same as opscale in R ? And sorry sir I am not get it  "you can transform both the  dependent and independent variables with TRANSREG"  do you mean I have to convert complete data in continuous or ordinal ? can you please explain me in simple way, I am so much confusing in this situation ,

Comment: TRANSREG is designed to do similar things as opscale, but there may be some differences in how they do it.  Logistic regression is done on the LOGIT of the dependent variable, so that is available. Same as logistic regression.

Comment: Okay sir, so I can use Logistic regression as well as opscale (optimal scaling ) if my boss tell me to use only python so both way is best?

Comment: I don't know about Python.

Comment: yes sir , but algorithm is same na?  in SAS LOGIT is same as logistic regression , so I will works on logistic regression using python ?

Comment: Sir thank you so much, okay I will do first in SAS  using LOGIT ,and once is done than I have to move to python.  thanks a lot...:)